# JArray Problems

Tags: c#, arrays, json, parsing

I have problems about JSON Parse and Jarray.Lenght.
My aim is in this app:
`metin` variable is my search string. Example I write "DDDDDD"; SOFTWARE search in JSON file, this "DDDDD" and write a console DDDDD's features.

```
         string data = File.ReadAllText(@"xxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

            JArray JSONParser = JArray.Parse(data);

       String aranacakisim = "metin";

        for (int i = 0; i <= JSONParser.lenght; i++) //fail line."Lenght"is not true.
        {


            if (JSONParser[i]["Ad"]=aranacakisim) //fail line
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ad: " + JSONParser[i]["Ad"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Soyad: " + JSONParser[i]["Soyad"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Bolum: " + JSONParser[i]["Bolum"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Sehir:" + JSONParser[i]["Sehir"]);
                Console.WriteLine("Sehir:" + JSONParser[i]["Telefon"]);
            }


        Console.ReadKey();


   JSON CODE 
       [
{
    "Ad": "Ali Kemal",
    "Soyad": "Sipahi",
    "Bolum": "Bilgisayar Muhendisligi",
    "Sehir": "Ankara",
    "Telefon": "05000000000"
},
{
    "Ad": "Neslihan",
    "Soyad": "Yağmur",
    "Bolum": "Tıp Fakültesi",
    "Sehir": "Malatya",
    "Telefon": "05000000001"
         }
       ]
```

How can I fix this error? Please write a true code. I will be crazy. Thank you very much!
/*Sorry for bad english*/

Errors comment

'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' can not be implicitly converted to 'bool'. There is an explicit conversion (do you have an incomplete assignment?)

Jarray does not have a length definition and no 'lenght' expansion method can be found that accepts a first argument in the Jarray type

Comment: post your json  iis the best way to  understand your problem

Comment: edited this thanks

Comment: *"How can I fix this error?"* > What error? I'm unable to find the error in your post. Could you please try to explain your actual problem in a bit more detail?

Comment: Jarray does not have a length definition and no 'lenght' expansion method can be found that accepts a first argument in the Jarray type //error's comment

Comment: 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' can not be implicitly converted to 'bool'. There is an explicit conversion (do you have an incomplete assignment?)

Comment: I am sorry I am BEGİNNER

Comment: Convert/write this code for me" type of questions are off-topic on SO.

Comment: Thanks for this information Salh ağabey.I will be careful about this statement :) I am very sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

The first error is due to the `JArray` class not having any property called `length`. But looking at [the documentation of the JArray class from Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) you can see that there is a `Count` property. So the following snippet should work:

`for (int i = 0; i <= JSONParser.Count; i++)`

The second error you get is most likely a typo, instead of comparing the values you are assigning the value (i.e. you're using `=` instead of `==`). For that case the following snippet should work:

`if ((string)JSONParser[i]["Ad"] == aranacakisim)`

Comment: Thank you but dont fixed.Your second line doesnt work :)

Comment: Error CS0019 '==' operator can not apply to 'JToken' and 'string' type operands

Comment: @AliKemalSipahi Ah I forgot to cast the value to string. I've updated my answer, this should work now.

Comment: You are number one!Thank you very much!My oxygen is SO.